# Android - Is there a way to specify a location when sharing into Google+ app?

Tags: android, location, share, google-plus

I am developing an app that allows the user to share an image to Google+.  When I share the image into Google+ from my app, I want to be able to specify the location associated with the image (not the user's present location as set by Google+). Is there a way to do this?  I.e., by setting some extra?  Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to prepopulate the location field for the shared post? This really isn't a question about image locations right, but more generally how to prepopulate the geo data of the post?

Comment: Yep, I want to prepopulate the geo data of the post.

Answer (score 1):

When ever user takes an image thruogh your app,take the corresponding Geopoints simultaniously and save it to a db. Whenever the user try to upload the photo take the corresponding Geopoints associated with the imagepath and post it to G+ I hope this will be a good possibility to solve this problem.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think the original question was asking how to share location to the Google+ app via intent and not directly via the Google+ API.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, images shared with Google+ need to be done via a ContentProvider. If you aren't already, can you add the LATITUDE and LONGITUDE columns to your content provider?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.html

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not possible to prepopulate the "Location" portion of a post on behalf of the user. If the user previously used the location field, it will be enabled for subsequent posts. If they turned it off, they would have to reenable it for subsequent posts.